# Lost access of Ubuntu partiton

Tags: grub2

I have installed Window 7 on Ubuntu 14.04.1 pre installed Laptop. Then  Windows written GRUB with it's own BOOTLOADER. Now it's only booting Windows 7.
I have done these..
Booted in live mode(try mode). Then `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt`(My Ubuntu partition),Then `sudo chroot /mnt`
Then `grub-install /dev/sda`, Which was a successful grub installation, Then `update-grub`.
Successfully detected all bootloader including Windows 7(Loader), But when I rebooted it's again going straight to Windows 7. What to do ?

Comment: You have to select which OS to boot in your BIOS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Comment: In the above link , scroll down to the troublehsoot section in the first answer. The exact location varies by bios

Comment: My situation is different , Read the whole thing carefully !!

Comment: No, your situation is the same, read the trouble shoot section and look at your bios.

Comment: But I didn't find any of these to be useful!!

Comment: From the link I gave you "TROUBLESHOOT

YOUR COMPUTER BOOTS DIRECTLY TO WINDOWS

This is a common problem and if you do not get a GRUB menu , re-installing or repairing grub will NOT HELP

Every BIOS is different, it my look like one of the following pictures:" continue reading ...

Answer (score 0):

I love boot repair but ONLY as a live CD.  The one and only time I ever installed it on an installation intending to fix that installation, it rendered the installation completely unbootable, so I beg you, please do not install boot repair on the drive you are trying to fix.  Always run boot repair from a live booting boot repair cd or self booting usb flash drive.

Answer (score -1):

Pulled from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) 
**2nd option : install Boot-Repair in Ubuntu**

- either from an Ubuntu live-session (boot your computer on a Ubuntu live-CD or live-USB then choose "Try Ubuntu") or from your installed Ubuntu session (if you can access it)
- connect to the Internet
- open a new Terminal, then type the following commands (press Enter after each line):

For Ubuntu 12.04

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
```

For Ubuntu 14.04 and newer

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kranich/cubuntu
```

- then type:

  `sudo apt-get update`

  `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)`
- After using the tool in an installed Ubuntu session, remove the PPA from your Software Sources.

**Using Boot-Repair**

**Recommended repair**
launch Boot-Repair from either :

the Dash (the Ubuntu logo at the top-left of the screen)

or by typing '`boot-repair`' in a terminal

Then click the "Recommended repair" button. When repair is finished, note the URL (paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX) that appeared on a paper, then reboot and check if you recovered access to your OSs.

If the repair did not succeed, indicate the URL to people who help you by email or forum.

Comment: I don't to use any tool,

Comment: The problems is not with grub, grub has been re-installed, and continuing to install or configure grub will not help, nor will boot repair. One has to select the OS to boot in the bios.